# Concatenating char buffer into a string

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, char, c-strings

In the following snippet, I receive the data until I have completely received all the data from the socket client. I keep on storing the data in a char buffer of size 300.

```
ssize_t b;
char buffer[300]
while((b = recv(socket_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
   // keep on receiving the data

}
```

But the problem is on each iteration, buffer gets refilled and old values are lost. How do I concatenate the buffer values into one, so that at the end of the loop I get the message as one complete string?

Comment: Make a separate array and copy each batch onto the end of that.

Comment: See [`strncat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/)

Comment: @johnelemans Could you please give an example?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Could you give an example in c?

Comment: what are you doing with the data? Eventually you're going to have to process it, whatever that entails in your situation. You can't simply keep receiving and concatenating forever. Do you know the max amount of data you can receive? If so, just make your buffer that size. If not, it depends on the protocol you're using to know when it's best to process and discard vs keep receiving.

Comment: Malloc 300 bytes instead, use another variable and add to it the amounts of bytes read at every iteration and check if you've still got enough to put in the buffer, if not then just realloc more bytes

Comment: @yano The maximum data I will receive is 1024 bytes. But I will receive the data in chunks. It could be a chunk of 10 bytes or 20 bytes or 200 bytes but not greater than that. After I receive the data, I will process that string

Comment: @VioAriton Could you give an example on how to do this?

Comment: @yano Would you know how to do this?

Comment: no time for a complete solution now, but you'll need to provide an offset into your receive buffer so the new data doesn't overwrite the old data. Something like `ssize_t b = 0; ssize_t bytesRecvSoFar = 0; char buffer[1024]; while((b = recv(socket_fd,buffer+bytesRecvSoFar, sizeof(buffer)-bytesRecvSoFar))) > 0 { ... bytesRecvSoFar += b; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this something like the following. I assume that buffer does not contain a string.

```
ssize_t b;
char buffer[300]
size_t n = 1;
char *s = calloc( 1, sizeof( char ) );

while((b = recv(socket_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {

    char *tmp = realloc( s, b + n );

    if ( !tmp )
    {
        // report an error
        break;
    }

    s = tmp;
    memcpy( s + n - 1, buffer, b );
    n += b;
    s[n - 1] = '\0';  
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly have you done?

Comment: @Amanda You are dynamically reallocating the array s and appending to it a new portion of data from buffer.

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the requirement and over-complicated the solution perhaps?

Comment: @Clifford I think she need an array of read data or a separate array from the buffer where a read string will be stored for further processing. So it is the only correct approach.

Comment: "only correct approach" is a bold claim, and tagging the question with keywords specific to your solution is a dubious practice ;-)

Comment: @Clifford She does not have a problem with the buffer. She is asking about how to build a string from several filled buffers.

Comment: Maybe.  I interpreted it as simply a need to accumulate the string in `buffer` and the issue one of simply not knowing how to append within the provided  buffer.  Later comments to my answer suggest that in fact reading a "line" is required - 300 characters is ample for most "line" input.  The question needs clarification perhaps.

Comment: Should there a corresponding free statement with this code? The run times throws memory leak errors.

Comment: @Amanda : Of course - it is only a "fragment" as is the code in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than passing `buffer` to `recv()`, pass the *address* of next element of `buffer` to be assigned and accumulate an index, adjusting the size argument of `recv()` to account for the data already written:

```
char buffer[300] ;
ssize_t buffer_index = 0 ;
ssize_t chunk = 0 ;

do 
{
   chunk = recv( socket_fd, 
                 &buffer[buffer_index], 
                 sizeof(buffer) - buffer_index - 1 ) ;

   if( chunk > 0 )
   {
       buffer_index += chunk ;
       buffer[buffer_index] = '\0' ;
   }

} while( buffer_index < sizeof(buffer) - 1 && 
         chunk > 0 ) ;
```

If rather then simply filling the buffer or timing out you need to terminate on a delimiter such as `\n` then you will need to read and inspect one character at a time:

```
char buffer[300] ;
ssize_t buffer_index = 0 ;
ssize_t status = 0 ;

do 
{
   status = recv( socket_fd, 
                  &buffer[buffer_index], 
                  1 ) ;

   if( status > 0 )
   {
       buffer_index++ ;
       buffer[buffer_index] = '\0' ;
   }

} while( ch != '\n' && 
         buffer_index < sizeof(buffer) - 1 && 
         status > 0 ) ;
```

A more complete example of a socket `readline()` function can be found at http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sockets/read_line.c.html for example.

Comment: Is there a way to detect the end of the message and exit the loop? The end of the message will be denoted `\r\n`

Comment: For some reason this does not work..just misses some data and concatenates the wrong ends

Comment: The `> 0 )` makes no sense here - if `recv` on the first loop returns `100`, and for example the second time returns `-1`, you need to exit right away. Another `size_t` variable is needed.

Comment: @KamilCuk Could you suggest how?

Comment: @KamilCuk Good point, needs some rework.  But Amanda's comment kind of changes the question in any case. Working on it.

Comment: @Amanda : If terminating on CR+LF is required, then you need to make that point in your question, otherwise it is a different question, requiring a different solution.

Comment: One issue I found with this approach is how do I receive a file as big as 10MB over the sockets? With a limited stack, I cannot initialize a buffer of 10MB.

Comment: @Amanda : Several options - including: 1) Allocate the buffer statically (`static char buffer[10*1024*1024]`), 2) allocate dynamically (`char* buffer = malloc( 10*1024*1024);`), 3) incrementally reallocate as in Vlad's answer, 4) use a memory mapped file if your system supports it (you don't say what the platform is), 5) save the data to a file rather then buffering the entire content in memory.

Comment: @Amanda ....Really though, that is a different question and you should post a new question with your platform and its constraints if you want a detailed answer.  If this is not an answer to your question, you should clarify the question - the question only mentions a buffer of 300 bytes. Vlad's answer is a solution to this secondary issue perhaps, but that is not what you asked - even if you (and Vlad) think you did.