# Continuously merge one char array into another char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I want to continuously merge `small_buf` into `big_buffer` while I receive the message in chunks. I do not how to do this.

```
char small_buf[100];
char big_buffer[2048];
ssize_t bytes_r = 0;
while((bytes_r = recv(socket_fd,small_buf,sizeof(small_buf)-1,0)) > 0) {
     small_buf[bytes_r] = '\0';
     // now merge small_buf with big_buffer
}
```

`big_buffer` represents the big single message which was received as smaller chunks from `recv`. How could I merge all `small_buf` into `big_buffer`?

Comment: Maintain an length of the message received so far. Then copy the new chunk starting from that point.

Comment: @EugeneSh. could you show an example with the answer?

Comment: Don't need to copy. You should just use `big_buffer` directly in `recv` by using the return value of `recv` to keep track of how much has already been written into `big_buffer`. That would be more efficient.

Comment: @MickaelB. That would be good for strings, but not for arbitrary binary data

Comment: still not enough here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847884/concatenating-char-buffer-into-a-string

Comment: @kaylum Could you give a small example with an answer?

Comment: @KamilCuk One of the answer by Clifford does not work. Is there a way with 2 arrays/.

Comment: The `does not work` does not mean anything. What do you mean by "does not work"? How does it "not work"? What happens? What does not happen? Please, try to be specific ;) It makes the program crash? The program never exits?

Comment: Why do you use two buffers? Can't you just receive into one buffer?

Comment: @KamilCuk I do not how could I do this with one buffer. The approach suggested by Clifford prints random sequence of strings and does not work

Comment: "prints" - there is no code in Clifford answer that prints anything. Are you sure you are receiving printable characters from the other side? Is the socket set in non-blocking mode?

Comment: When I inspect the buffer by printing I see it @KamilCuk

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I am the one who is sending them

Comment: @KamilCuk Sometimes it just prints out of sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just receive the data into the buffer:

```
// the buffer to read the data to
char buffer[2048];
// position in buffer
size_t pos = 0;

for (
        // count of bytes received in this loop or error
        ssize_t received = 0; 
        ( 
             received = recv(socket_fd, 
                 // we are reading into position pos into the buffer
                 &buffer[pos],
                 // the size of buffer decreases each iteration
                 // leave space for zero terminating character `- 1`
                 // I assume that when `pos == sizeof(buffer) - 1` then `recv` will just return 0 or -1.
                 sizeof(buffer) - pos - 1,
                 0)
         # compare received > 0 
         ) > 0; 
         ) {
     // increase the position in buffer
     pos += received;
     // optionally: add `if (pos == sizeof(buffer) - 1) break;`         
     // also assert that all received characters are isprint()
}
// zero terminate the buffer, if you want to
// otherwise remove the `-1` above
buffer[pos] = '\0';
```

and without comments:

```
char buffer[2048];
size_t pos = 0;
for (ssize_t received = 0; 
         ( received = recv(socket_fd, &buffer[pos], sizeof(buffer) - pos - 1, 0)) > 0; 
         ) {
     pos += received;
}
buffer[pos] = '\0';

printf("Received %zu characters: `%.*s`\n", pos, (int)pos, buffer);
```

> The condition to terminate is the sequence \r\n\r\n Is there a way to detect this?

```
char buffer[2048];
size_t pos = 0;
while (7) { // lucky 7!
    const ssize_t received = recv(socket_fd, &buffer[pos], 1, 0);
    // handle error
    // TODO: for example handle EINTR here
    if (received < 0) {
       break;
    }
    // handle empty loop
    if (received == 0) {
       continue;
    }

    // increment position in buffer
    assert(received == 1);
    pos += 1;
    // zero terminate the buffer
    assert(pos < sizeof(buffer));
    buffer[pos] = '\0';

    // if we have more then 4 characters, check for ending sequence
    if (pos >= 4) {
       if (memcmp(buffer[pos - 4], "\r\n\r\n", 4) == 0) {
           // sequence \r\n\r\n found
           break;
        }
    }

    // check for no more memory
    if (pos == sizeof(buffer) - 1) {
        // no more memory
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `(received = recv(socket_fd, &buffer[pos], sizeof(buffer) - pos - 1, 0)) > 0`?

Comment: @S.S.Anne I see it's confusing to ppl not used to using comma that way. I'll edit it.

Comment: Lol. Both are pretty ugly :)

Comment: @KamilCuk I know comma but the solution I proposed is a two-in-one. I guess it doesn't matter, the same code will probably be generated anyway.

Comment: @Amanda `.... a way to detect this?` the simplest is just to read character by character and remember last 4 characters read and compare them with the sequence. That sequence looks like AT or Hayes response separator.

Comment: I was writing an answer from my phone (so not very fast) and it was similar... except for that for-loop that is quite scary! :) I personally prefer using `for` in cases in which I know the number of iteration required (repeat something _for N times_). Otherwise I use while.

Comment: @amanda `
char buf[2048];
ssize_t res;
size_t bytes=0, spaceLeft = sizeof(buffer)-1;

while((res = recv(socket_fd, buf+bytes, spaceLeft, 0)) > 0)
{
     bytes += res;
     spaceLeft -=res;
}
// manage socket closure!
// ...

// Useful in case the received data is a string
buf [bytes] = 0;
`

Comment: @Amanda In order to detect exit condition I would use `strstr ()`. In order to do this you will need to append string terminator after each received chunk.

Comment: @KamilCuk How could I accommodate a case where I want to receive data around 7MB? Increasing the buffer size of 7MB sometimes does not receive whole data